# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Source Error:

```
Line 110:        </div><!-- /.site-header-wrap -->
Line 111:
Line 112:        @RenderBody()
Line 113:
Line 114:        <section class="flat-row mail-chimp">
```

Source File:

> C:\Users\nghie\source\repos\EcommrceBasic\clothbazar\ClothBazar.Web\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml    Line: 112

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is.

Comment: Please do post the view code and the controller action.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it for a generic answer

Comment: How are you trying to use this "shared layout" file? Please add some details to your question.